# How to auto save and auto load all properties in winforms C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to auto save all properties winforms when closed and  auto load all properties winforms when load ? C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
namespace SControl
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Controls.Count; i++)
            {
                System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Controls[i]));
                Stream stream = File.Open("test.xml", FileMode.Create);
                x.Serialize(stream, Controls[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean properties like window size, positions, mode etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Your question is a little unclear, but*

If you require saving/loading of the **Form Layout** have a look at

[Windows Forms User Settings in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/UserSettings.aspx)

If you require saving/loading an **object/class** have a look at

[Load and save objects to XML using serialization](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/xml_serializationasp.aspx)

**EDIT:**

This will show you how to persist certain settings for form properties.

[Save and Restore Setings of a .NET Form using XML](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dolson/SaveandRestoreSetingsofa.NETFormusingXML11252005230324PM/SaveandRestoreSetingsofa.NETFormusingXML.aspx)

Also have a look at [The Application Automation Layer - Using XML To Dynamically Generate GUI Elements--Forms And Controls](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/aal-5a.aspx)

All these will guide you in the direction you need to go.

I think the main objective here is

- Figure out when to save and when to
  load, and where to store/retrieve
  these settings.
- Are you storing these settings per
  user? In a database? In a xml file?
- Next you need to identify which
  properties you will be
  saving/restoring per control. Simple
  location/size settings might not cut
  it as controls will have various
  complexities (Button, TextBox,
  Gridview, ListView)
- Now you need to figure out how to
  iterate ALL controls on the form.
  Buttons, Textboxes, Panels, Controls
  in Controls (controls in panels), and
  maybe even your User Controls. This
  can be done using recursion.
- Now you need to decide on the
  structure of the xml file (if you opt
  to use xml). This should pretty much
  look like a tree structure, as you
  would look at the form, and its
  controls, and their controls, as a
  tree structure.

Comment: i like xml object serialization but how to save and load ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any automatic method built into the `Form` base class, but adding it yourself isn't hard.

You could tap the window load and close events to cache off all relevant properties to a backing store and then reload them later.

Register an event handler to the `Form.Load` and `Form.Closing` event handlers. When `Form.Closing` occurs, save the forms state to a file or database. When `Form.Load` occurs, check to see if a saved state is present and if so, reload the from from the saved state.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually code which properties to be saved.

A convenient method is to svae these personalized settings to [Windows Forms Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx).

Sample code snippet:

```
//save the winform position and size upon closing
private void Form1_FormClosed(
   object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.FormPosition = this.Location;
    Properties.Settings.Default.FormSize = this.Size;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}

//load the winform position and size upon loading
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Size = Properties.Settings.Default.FormSize;
    this.Location = Properties.Settings.Default.FormPosition;
}
```

More references:

- [Using Settings in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28VS.80%29.aspx)
- [Any good examples of how to use Applications settings](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/5e509b2a-76da-4d91-89b5-9fa8cb50fc8f)
- [Use Windows Forms Application Settings to Personalize Your Applications](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/34273)

Comment: that all element ? Textbox1, Textbox2, Textbox3 ... ?

Comment: Can to start using function AutoLoad();
Can Exit using function SaveAll();
?

Comment: If you allow the users to personalize things like form control properties (e.g. dock, font etc), you can save them as well, but you'll have to code it manually for saving and loading. astander has provided a good reference for a more automated method using serialization which is another alternative. `AutoLoad` and `Exit` can be replaced with the form events `Form.Load` and `Form.Closing` like what Ryan Michela mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The process of turning objects like forms into something that could be saved is called serialization. Unfortunately I don't think there's an out-of-box way to serialize forms in WinForm. I did find [How to Clone/Serialize/Copy & Paste a Windows Forms Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ControlCloneTst.aspx), and since forms are also controls, you might be able to serialize the properties using the code.