# C# Application Saving

Tags: savefiledialog

I have created an application in C# using visual studio 2010. The application uses a database and a ton of data bound controls.

I need to save a copy of the running application with what changes the user has made to a file they can double click and get their saved state back in the application.

I know I need to use a SaveFileDialog but other than I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the controls are bound to data through datasets you could perhaps serialize and deserialize the underlying datasets to/from XML files in order to create some kind of "offline data file storage" feature.

Before introducing such a feature into your application you should, however, consider all the potential database synchronization issues that are potentially created though preservation of such a saved state within your application clients.

If you really only want to preserve window *layout* properties (such as window size, grid column width, sorted column, splitter positions etc) you have to focus on those properties only.

Here is a thread with a [similar discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076259/how-to-auto-save-and-auto-load-all-properties-in-winforms-c)

Comment: Thanks very much. Done all that now and it's working but when I deploy the application using visual studios setup wizard i get an error saying access denied to the path of my xml file which needs to be updated in the program files directory where the application installs too.

Comment: I've used Path.GetTempPath() to create the xml file. Is this correct?

Comment: You should certainly not save the file in the program files folder! It is both a restricted path in addition to the fact that any user accessing the workstation will share the programs installed there. Instead use the Application Data path: `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) `

Comment: You probably shouldn't use the temp path either (due to it's temporary nature)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Will save it in the app data folder.