# Retain TextBox value between app launches

Tags: .net, winforms, textbox

I have a TextBox in my .NET application that control various settings in my application.  The values entered are likely remain the same on each execution of the app.  I'd like the data to be retained so on the next launch of the application the values are already populated.

What's the best way to handle this?  Write out the values to a file on ApplicationExit and then reread them on launch?  There's got to be a more clever way...

Thanks.

Comment: You know, having 10 questions, one accepted answer and only one upvote does not really create the right incentives for people to eagerly answer your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at **Using Your Application Settings Class with Your Application** section in this document:

**[Persisting Application Settings in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973902.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

[ApplicationSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could write them a to a file (including a 'settings' file), a database, the registry, or some remote webservice.  Either way, the pattern is pretty much the same.  You aren't missing out on a secret handshake that makes WinForms do this automatically :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to save the form's state. If so, check out this question/answers.

[How to auto save and auto load all properties in winforms C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076259/how-to-auto-save-and-auto-load-all-properties-in-winforms-c)